# HasMany relation not working in Adonis framework using mongodb database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, adonis.js

In my case, hasMany relation not working 
database like

`Users.js`

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dc5617ac22c2921fc32b1f0"),
    "name" : "vikas",
    "email" : "vikas@gmail.com",
    "contact_ids" : [ 
        "5dc5572ee6143821e43ece31"
    ],

    "created_at" : ISODate("2019-11-08T12:37:12.452Z"),
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2019-11-08T12:37:12.456Z")
}
```

`Contact.js`

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dc5572ee6143821e43ece31"),
    "name" : "vikas Contacts",
    "mobile" : 95754681658,
    "user_id" : "5dc5617ac22c2921fc32b1f0",
    "created_at" : ISODate("2019-11-08T11:53:15.781Z"),
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2019-11-08T11:53:15.786Z")
}
```

and I'm applying relation on USERS model

`User.js`

```
  /** get many contacts */
  contacts() {
    return this.belongsToMany('App/Models/Contact', '_id', 'contact_ids')
    // hasMany(relatedModel, primaryKey, foreignKey)
  }
```

and the final result is  // OUTPUT

```
        {
            "_id": "5dc5617ac22c2921fc32b1f0",
            "name": "vikas",
            "email": "vikas@gmail.com",
            "contact_ids": [
                "5dc5572ee6143821e43ece31"
            ],
            "created_at": "2019-11-08T12:37:12.452Z",
            "updated_at": "2019-11-08T12:37:12.456Z",
            "contacts": []
        }
```

when I applying has many relations it doesn't show contacts list in an array

Comment: Can you please share your entity relationship diagram?

Comment: I'm using MongoDB database, I don't know how to make a relationship database in MongoDB,
In this case, users are the master table and user_id use in the contacts table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your `User` model like :

```js
...
contacts() {
    return this.hasMany('App/Models/Contact', '_id', 'contact_ids')
}
...
```

Comment: I use this but doesn't work
But in users list contact relation, not retrieving.
the output like [see the output image](http://prntscr.com/pvwj1k)

Comment: Can you please share your controller code (getting model data)?

Comment: here is the link of my controller code  [UserController.js](http://prntscr.com/pw8of7)

Comment: Can you try (controller) this : const users = await User.query().with('contacts').fetch()

Comment: Yes, I just test this from my userController.js 
but it doesn't work.
same output   **"contacts": []**

Comment: Mongodb is not supported in AdonisJS database provider. Which project do you use?

Comment: Sorry, But I'm using MongoDB on my adonis framework 
I use  **"lucid-mongo": "^3.1.6",  "mongodb-core": "^3.2.7"** packages for mongodb connection.

Comment: Hi, my skills in MongoDB do not allow me to answer your question. I advise you to put your question on the lucid-mogo github or on forum.adonisjs.com

Comment: Thanks to all, This answer really help me,